# How do I make something (a string) appear after some seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, delay

I just want to make the string "¿Where are you?" fade in after around 5 seconds after loading the site. Is there is an easy way to do it? It made be obvious but I'm pretty new to this stuff.
Thanks a lot

Comment: PHP won't do this, you need Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need javascript for that, in particular, the jQuery javascript library will make it very easy to do.

You need to add this in your `<head>` section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
         $("body").append("<p>¿Where are you?</p>").fadeIn();
      }, 5000);
   });
</script>
```

The first `<script>` loads the jQuery library which in this situation lets you easily run code after the document has loaded and has handy shortcuts for fading in elements. The second `<script>` is where you set a timer for 5000 milliseconds, after which you add some text to the document and fade it in.

That'll get you started, but you'll need to know javascript and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to take this further...

Comment: Note that only the first line is needed in the **<head>** section.  The rest can be moved to the body.

Comment: @simshaun, technically both can be moved to the body, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Crap I could never manage to run JQuery in my blog. I just need to copy the jquery library to any path on my server and copy that path right? Could you tell me what's the file I have to copy? I couldn't do it last time and ended up annoying the one that tried to help me =@

Comment: @Lisandro Vaccaro... there are two options. You can either copy the file to your server, in which case the jQuery homepage (jquery.com) has links to those files. But if you don't want to go to that trouble my code as provided above works by linking directly to jquery's website - there's no need for a download.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the setTimeout function in javascript to achieve this.

something like this:

setTimeout("alert('¿Where are you?')", 5000);

Comment: I'd love to use plain old javascript. But I have a question, how do I just call a string? Not an alert –

Comment: you can write a function and setTimeout(myFunc, 5000); where the myFunc would "call/manipulate" the string.

Comment: don't just copy and paste the pseudo code i wrote.  myFunc is intend to be a function written w/ codes to create what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

- Using jQuery: Try a [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) combined with a [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/),
- or plain javascript:

  ```
  setTimeout("alert('Surprise!')", 5000);
  ```

Comment: I'd love to use plain old javascript. But I have a question, how do I just call a string? Not an alert